# Group_Concat versus iterating results for pagination

Tags: mysql

I am wondering whether it would be faster to use Group_Concat or simple fetch iteration to get a list of results (perhaps a couple thousand) in order to save the result IDs for pagination through the results for display at my site.  I am trying to optimize simple pagination through results without unneccesary complex queries.

Right now I am doing the search query (it can get complex) every time a user paginates through a list of results at my site (site members for example).  I am wondering if doing a group concat to get the pertinent user IDs one time (getting the resulting string of IDs) , and then parsing the string to build an array of results (that I could save) would ultimately be faster for when the user is paginating through the results.  I could save the array of IDs if the PHP session and do an easy search for just the needed IDs when displaying a particular page of results. (This assumes the search criteria have not changed obviously).

I do not want to iterate with thousands of fetch's to build that array (in PHP) if it is faster to get one row with all the result IDs, then save it and use that array for fetching individual results for display, 20 at a time depending on what page the user wants to see.

So, the basic question:  Is the group concat faster than iterating through all the results to build an array of IDs?

Comment: You could try it. However, fetching every row to paginate is very inefficient. Consider using [`limit` and `offset`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) to fetch a page at a time from the database. Add a query or page cache if necessary.